# Python: How to prevent special characters in input

Tags: python, string, python-3.9

My problem is when I enter a number in the input field, it becomes number with special character. I don't know why it's adding extra characters to input. You can see the example. I entered just 5.2 and it became '5.2&

```
"""
length of rectangle = a
width of rectangle = b
calculate the area and perimeter of the rectangle
"""

a = 6
b = float(input("width: "))

area = a*b
perimeter = (2*a) + (2*b)

print("area: " + str(area) + " perimeter: " + str(perimeter))
```

```
File "c:\Users\HP\OneDrive - Karabuk University\Belgeler\Downloads\first.py", line 8, in <module>
b = float(input("width: "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5.2&
```

Could you please help me?

Comment: Could you share a little bit more of the code because `b = float(input("width: "))` in itself doesn't produce the error

Comment: I edited with the code, thank you for the response

Comment: What do you mean by "prevent"? It's one thing to strip them out after they're entered. It's another thing to not let the user type them at all; and typically, normal expected behavior for terminal applications is just to prompt a second time when input is invalid. If someone pastes a UUID into a numeric field by mistake, you don't want to take only the numbers out of the UUID and treat that as if it's what they meant to enter; you want to let them enter a real, valid number.

Comment: Sorry, I may not express my problem clearly because obviously English is not my second language and I am a beginner in coding. What I am trying to say is when I run the code and I enter the input, it becomes the version I did not enter (as you can see in the example i entered 5.2 and it seems different). I am wondering why it is different?

Comment: The example code runs fine. I posted code that separates the functions `input` and `float` to see which produces the error on your system. Let us know if and how you solve the issue because the posted code does not and should not produce the error. Sometimes a function is accidentally modified in a program but does not happen in this program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me It's working fine...See my output..

Note: It throws error at last line in your code because you can't concatenate a `str` with an `int`.

So, you need to convert `int` to `str` before concatenating your variables

```
a = 6
b = float(input("width: "))
print(b)

area = a*b
perimeter = (2*a) + (2*b)

print("area: " + str(area) + " perimeter: " + str(perimeter))
```

#output

```
width: 5.2
5.2
area: 31.200000000000003 perimeter: 22.4
```

### Alternate solution 2

Idk why it's adding extra chars to your user input...Anyway you can filter user input once entered as follows.

```
import re
a = 6
b = (input("width: "))
b=str(b)
b=re.sub("[^0-9^.]", "", b)

b=float(b)
print(b)

area = a*b
perimeter = (2*a) + (2*b)

print("area: " + str(area) + " perimeter: " + str(perimeter))
```

output #

```
width: 5.2b
5.2
area: 31.200000000000003 perimeter: 22.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I add str to the last line but the error is same.

Comment: Updated the answer check alternate solution posted

Comment: There should not be an issue with the `input` function. It is a built-in function in python.exe. I suggest uninstalling python and reinstalling python to try to fix the problem. And possibly restarting the system. Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

```
"""
length of rectangle = a
width of rectangle = b
calculate the area and perimeter of the rectangle
"""

"""
We cannot replicate this error.
b = float(input("width: "))
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5.2&

Debug by breaking down the code to see which function is the source of the 
error.
"""
a = 6
# b = float(input("width: "))
s = input("width: ")
print("s= " + s)
b = float (s)
area = a*b
perimeter = (2*a) + (2*b)

print("area: " + str(area) + " perimeter: " + str(perimeter))
```

Output

```
width: 5.2
s= 5.2
area: 31.200000000000003 perimeter: 22.4
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking time to help. I tried what you say, unfortunatelly error is still same (adding same chars). I think I'm gonna cry but anyways appreciate it.

Comment: Restart your system ;) what is the value printed for s. Does float error still?

Comment: b = float (s)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '5.2&

Comment: So the error is related to the input function. Weird.

Comment: Have u checked my upadted solution? ---I've mentioned as Alternate solution 2